# Add an action to filter nested APIs

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have two models with one to many relationship and I would like to add an action in order to be able to list all object A (startups) with at least one nested object B having attribute active to True.

I have added this extra action however it's returning an error:

> 'Q' object is not callable

Here is my code:

```
@action(detail=False, methods=['get'])
def get_active_startups(self, request, pk=None):
    Startup.objects.annotate(
        active_investments=Count('startup_investments', filter=Q(startup_investments__active=True)).filter(
            active_investments__gt=0))
```

If this code works, will it hit the DB each time I request this list? If so, is there a better way to do the same on serializer level?

Here are my serializers:

```
class InvestmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:

        model = Investment
        fields = ('id', 'Investment_title', 'collected_amount', 'goal_percentage', 'number_of_investors',
                  'days_left', 'active')


class StartupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    startup_investments = InvestmentSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Startup
        fields = ('id', 'header', 'title', 'description', 'tags', 'card_image',
                  'logo_image', 'main_img', 'startup_investments')
```

I want to to list startups with as least one invetment having field active set to true.

Comment: I think you have parentheses problem. Try this: Startup.objects.annotate(active_investments=Count('startup_investments', filter=Q(startup_investments__active=True))).filter(active_investments__gt=0)

Comment: How is `Q` defined?